# Flexibility in timing on pre-booked nsb.no train tickets?

Tags: trains, norway

If travelling around Norway via train using pre-booked tickets from nsb.no, are the tickets explicitly ONLY valid for the stated train departure, or would they be valid on an equivalent route?

eg. If I miss an r10 train from Oslo airport to Oslo S, could I catch any r10 train?  Any similar train (eg. the r11)? Or would I pay a penalty?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, NSB tickets bought online are only valid on the exact train you bought the ticket for. Full price tickets can be cancelled and refunded (minus a processing fee) before the scheduled departure, but if you choose to take a different train, you will have to buy a new ticket for the new connection.

Tickets for shorter train trips within the greater Oslo area are priced according to the zone based fares of the local transportation authority 'Ruter'. If you order an online ticket from the airport to the central station on nsb.no, you will actually pay NOK 101 for a four zone (4N, 3Ø, 2Ø and 1) Ruter ticket, but it will only allow you to travel on the designated train. If you buy an 'on-the-spot', regular Ruter ticket instead just before travelling, you will also pay NOK 101, but the ticket is valid for arbitrary public transport (also bus, tram, subway or ferry) and transfers within those zones for the next 2.5 hours.

Ruter tickets can be bought at ticket machines (there are plenty of them at the airport), on board the train (in most cases with a surcharge if you could have bought the ticket before boarding) or with the [RuterBillett](https://ruter.no/en/buying-tickets/mobile-ticket-app/) app, which allows payment by credit card. They don't sell online tickets through any web-based channels and there is really no point in buying the ticket in advance.

Comment: Well that is weird... nsb.no seems to allow me to get all the way to paying for a ticket from Oslo lufhaven to Oslo S as in this handy link:
https://www.nsb.no/en/booking/select-trip?from=Oslo%20Lufthavn&to=Oslo%20S&departureDatetime=2019-02-06%2013%3A44&returnDatetime=2019-02-13%2014%3A00&petFree=false&pasCats=1&numPasCats=1

Comment: But thankyou very much for answering my main question and flagging up where it seemed wrong!  I have booked a 4 hour, more expensive train out of Oslo S for which I certainly would not want to pay twice!

Comment: @Mark_Anderson You are absolutely right. I was not aware that NSB sells online tickets for local transport around Oslo. I have edited my answer and added some details. The conclusion stands however: There is no point in buying the ticket in advance.